# iPhone App - Open Webpage - Appstore approval

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Just a quick question. For the sake of time we plan on just creating an app which opens the browser and points to our website. Down the line an update will provide the rest of the functionality.

In your experience, would this app get approval? If not what would I need to do to get approval?

Cheers,
RJ

Comment: I dont think Apple will reject the app. Your app will make no diff with Safari browser so I suggest you to add little more functionality instead of simply using the browser & then submit to Apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think it will be approved:

> - **2.9** Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected
> - **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment
>     value may be rejected
> - **2.13** Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't quote from the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) directly because it requires a developer account, I can say that point 2.12 suggests that that app would not get approved.

My suggestion is that you read the review guidelines to get an idea of what is required to get approval.

Answer (score 0):

I know of apps on the App Store that are nothing more than a UIWebView. See this link for proof of it: [App Store and UIWebView](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/70355-app-store-and-uiwebview.html)

In order to enhance the user's experience, you could also consider using [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)